# Is there an adjective meaning "dog like"?

Tags: vocabulary

Feline is an adjective meaning "cat like". Then is there an adjective meaning "dog like"?

Comment: This is general reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Canine", or if you want to be infuriatingly erudite, you could use the noun "canid" in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: Sorry, you beat me, I didn't see your answer when I was posting mine.

Comment: Forgive me for being pedantic, but *canine* is actually a subset of *canid*.  Canines are dogs and wolves, canids include vulpines which are foxes. (From the fox avatar, you may understand why I like to make this distinction.)

Comment: LOL!   Yes, that is probably true in scientific discourse, but i'm sure the word "canine" came before the zoological category "canine".

Comment: @KitΘδς ...and `lupine` would be wolf-like. It can be used in many of the same situations as "canine" and is a bit more commonly used this way, but implies a look that is a bit more serious or deadly.

Comment: So if you have lupine for wolves and vulpine for foxes but both of these along with dogs are also canines then there isn't a word for dog-like?

Comment: @Martin Beckett - As this answer states, it would be "canine". "Canid" could perhaps be used for the entire family of species, but I don't hear it used much. "Lupine" is used often to designate a look, while "canine" more for dog-like behavior. My favorite example: "To err is human, to forgive, canine."

Comment: And of course, "vulpine" is a genus that is entirely independent of "canine";  "canines" and "vulpines" are distinct genuses of "canids", and do not overlap.

Comment: @Kyle - thanks, I thought canidae was just the plural of canine

Comment: No worries.  I just learned it, myself.  ;-)

Comment: To differentiate from canine you could say kýōnic, and refer back to the ancient Greek for dog, kýōn. I doubt anyone would have any idea what you meant, so unless you really don't want to use canine or lupine I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Canine.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canine

canine adj 
1: of or resembling that of a dog  
2: of or relating to dogs or to the family (Canidae) including the canids